# Numbers Brain Teaser

Tags: mathematics, rebus, number-sequence

I've come across a strange brain teaser on one of those sheets with things like:

[image: (man overboard)]
(man overboard)

So here's the puzzle:

> 0 - 20
>
> 10 - 3
>
> 14 - 29
>
> 96 - 72
>
> 1977

I've been trying to do some math on this, but it might also be a more literal answer. Unsure if the hyphens are subtraction or something else - again, it might not even be math related. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the display exactly like this in the original problem?

Comment: Yes, it was a bit more centered than how it shows up here, but it was in that order, stacked on top of each other, no lines separating the rows or anything like that.

Comment: Possibly useful? rot13(([frr "FZIGV orngf HZN"](https://newspaperarchive.com/kennebec-journal-jan-20-1977-p-23/))

Comment: That's such a common basketball score and that specific game isn't noteworthy.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a phrase like

> "no difference in the end"
>  
>  or
>  
>  "no difference at the end"

because

> the difference between two numbers is figured out by subtraction.

however

> the last expression is not subtraction, so there's "no difference at the end."

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you elaborate _why_ you believe this to be the answer?

Comment: The minus sign indicates a difference calculation. There is no difference in the end line. “no difference in the end” is a common english phrase.